# Yii : Using Two models in single Form

Tags: php, yii, model

I have a Three models

1. Books
2. Categories
3. Category mapping

I want to store relation of books and their categories in Category mapping Table. By getting the details of categories using `checkboxlist` in yii in the the `Form` of Books.

Like

```
Book Name: ______________

Book Author: ______________

Book Published:  _____________

Categories---------------------------------------------

[] Educational  [] Academic [] Spiritual []Self Help   

-------------------------------------------------------

(Save)
```

For Eg: 
In Category mapping Table

```
Book ID | Category ID 
   1    |      2      
   1    |      5
   1    |      7
   2    |      2
```

In the `controller/Book.php`

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Book;

        if(isset($_POST['Book']))
        {

           $bid=$model->book_id;
            if(isset($_POST['Category'])){

                foreach ($_POST['Category'] as $category) {
                    $category = new Category();
                    $category->attributes=$_POST['Category'];
                    $category->map_book_id=$bid;
                    $category[] = $category;
                }
                if(!empty($category)){
                    $category->save();
                }
            }

            if($model->save()){

                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->book_id));
            }

        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
            'category'=>$category,
        ));
    }
```

It is not working. Please help.

Comment: print `$category->getErrors();` and `$model->getErrors();` in ur if conditions when save is unsuccessful.

Comment: Shouldn't the `$category->save();` be written inside the foreach loop. Why to write `$category[] = $category;`?

Comment: I was trying to save all at once as it is given in yii application development book

Comment: Then you will need to loop them again and save each of them. Anyways the `$category` variable cannot be available outside the `foreach`.

Comment: that's good idea but where to use the     $category = new Category(); because we need to render the same in form.  if it is put in the beginning there is a problem if we put it inside foreach then there is a problem in rendering the same.

Comment: Posted an answer just to give an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a Book is saved, you wish to save the Categories for it in the `Category Mapping` table.

Lets say that the Model for it is `CategoryMapping`.

Try -

```
//After saving the Book, you have the Book Id in `$bid` variable.

$category_arr = array();

if(isset($_POST['Category'])){

    foreach ($_POST['Category'] as $category) {
        $category_map = new CategoryMapping();
        $category_map->category_id = $category;
        $category_map->book_id = $bid;

        //..... some other attributes to set

        if($category_map->save()) {
            $category_arr[] = $category;
        } else {
            print_r($category_map->getErrors());    //Just for debugging
        }
    }

}
```

Then -

```
$this->render('create',array(
    'model'=>$model,
    'category'=>$category_arr,
));
```

Comment: if we use `$category = new Category();` inside then how to render it to form

Comment: You wish to display the selected categories in the form? If yes, then do you need a simple array or object like findall? Your code from the view could give more insight here about categories.